# AutoHotkey: While 2 keys are pressed = press 3rd key?

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotkey, how can I do the following:

While SPACE and "either or a combination of [A, S, D, W]" are pressed down at the same time, send key LSHIFT every X milliseconds; do this until SPACE and and A, S, D, W are not pressed.

I'm a beginner. I tried multiple ways, but it didn't work at all.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried this, it does nothing:

```
q::

Loop
{
    If GetKeyState("Space", "P") && GetKeyState("w", "P")
    {
        Send, {LShift}
        Sleep, 500

        If Not GetKeyState("Space", "P") && GetKeyState("w", "P")
        {
            Pause
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
x := 500 ;your x

~Space::
sleep, 500  ;this is extra time given to you and not X . Dont Edit.
loop,
{
if GetKeyState("W","p") or GetKeyState("A","p") or GetKeyState("S","p") or GetKeyState("D","p")
    Send, {LShift}
else
    break
sleep, x
}
return
```

Enjoy

Comment: Would you mind if I edited the question to include the keys asked for?  I think it adds clarity to the answer.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Edited the question . That's none of my business . Please

Comment: sorry.  I meant your answer -- not the question.